# How to accept input for a list of objects using checkboxes in a form

Tags: forms, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-data-jpa

I have a scenario with 2 entities:

1)Student:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_registration")
public class Student
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String firstName;
    @Column
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Hobby> hobbies;

//constructors (default, all params), getters and setters
}
```

2)Hobbies:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hobby")
public class Hobby
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hobby_id")
    private Student student;
    @Column
    private String name;

//contructors (default, Hobby(name, student), getters and setters)
}
```

**I want to input each checkbox option from a group of checkboxes as a hobby with name equal to the value of the checkbox**

Here is my JSP section for the above:

```
<div class="form">
    <form:form action="success" modelAttribute="student" onsubmit="return validate()">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="label">First Name</div>
            <div class="field">
                <form:input path="firstName" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="label">Last Name</div>
            <div class="field">
                <form:input path="lastName" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="label">Hobbies</div>
            <div class="field">
                <form:checkbox path="hobbies" id="hobby1Checkbox" value="Hobby 1" />
                <label class="sublabel" for="hobby1Checkbox">Hobby 1</label>
                <form:checkbox path="hobbies" id="hobby2Checkbox" value="Hobby 2" />
                <label class="sublabel" for="hobby2Checkbox">Hobby 2</label>
                <form:checkbox path="hobbies" id="hobby3Checkbox" value="Hobby 3" />
                <label class="sublabel" for="hobby3Checkbox">Hobby 3</label>
            </div>
        </div>
</form:form>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
StudentService stuServ;
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
  return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/registration")
public String registrationRedirect(ModelMap studentModel)
{
   studentModel.addAttribute("student", new Student());   
   studentModel.addAttribute("hobby", new Hobby());
   return "registration";
}
@PostMapping("/success")
public String sayHello(@ModelAttribute("registeredStudent") Student student) {
   
   stuServ.addStudent(student);
  return "success";
}
}
```

I understand that what I have done is incorrect, since I cannot map a String value from a checkbox to a list of objects (List)
However I am unable to find a way to achieve the same. I was looking into possible solutions using a Converter or a PropertyEditor but I am new to Spring MVC and I'm confused.

***Update:**

I have observed that upon adding a parameterized constructor within the Hobby class with only the name as the argument, I am able to directly pass the value to the Hobby object using the checkboxes, since the String value of the checkboxes is initialized to the Hobby name via the aforementioned contructor.

This works if I am only to use the hobby name for my registration success view, **however another obvious issue is that the student field of the Hobby class never gets initialized since only the contructor *Hobby(name)* is getting invoked**, hence the relationship isn't bidirectional. Student field remains null in the Hobby class.

Kindly assist with appropriate ways to handle the situation. I am unable to think of ways with which I might let Spring know that which student am I assigning the Hobby selected by the checkbox to.

**Edit with respect to my earlier provided answer:**

Another issue arises if I create a repository for Hobby entity:

```
public interface HobbyRepository extends JpaRepository<Hobby, Integer>
{
    boolean findByName(String hobby);
}
```

The checkbox String value initialization for hobbies does not work anymore. Earlier the constructor with name parameter for Hobby entity did the job but on addition of Hobby repository I am getting the following expected error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
> Validation failed for object='registeredStudent'. Error count: 1
> org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
> Field error in object 'registeredStudent' on field 'hobbies': rejected value [Singing,Sketching,Swimming]; codes [typeMismatch.registeredStudent.hobbies,typeMismatch.hobbies,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [registeredStudent.hobbies,hobbies]; arguments []; default message [hobbies]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'hobbies'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'Singing'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Singing"]

Pretty much, the Hobby with name = the String value of the checkboxes isn't being able to initialize anymore. I have tried removing the Hobby repository and it works perfectly. **Any further insight would be appreciated** as the only possible solution for now appears to be adding an extra *List<String> field* in my *Student* POJO class and using the values from checkboxes passed in the field to initialize the Hobby objects contained in *Student.hobbies*

Answer (score 1):

In my controller, the current student object passed as *ModelAttribute* can be assigned to each of the hobbies belonging to the current student object, thereby completing the bidirectional relationship, as follows:

```
   @PostMapping("/success")
   public String sayHello(@ModelAttribute("registeredStudent") Student student) {
       for(Hobby h : student.getHobbies())
       {
           h.setStudent(student);
       }
       stuServ.addStudent(student);
      return "success";
   }
```

I had to exclude the mapped fields, i.e. *hobbies* in Student entity and *student* in Hobby entity from the hashcode and equals methods in the respective entities, in order to prevent *StackOverFlow Error* due to infinite nesting of the entities

This works as a solution, however there might be better ways to approach this problem.

**Edit:**

Another issue arises if I create a repository for Hobby entity:

```
public interface HobbyRepository extends JpaRepository<Hobby, Integer>
{
    boolean findByName(String hobby);
}
```

The checkbox String value initialization for hobbies does not work anymore. Earlier the constructor with name parameter for Hobby entity did the job but on addition of Hobby repository I am getting the following expected error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
> Validation failed for object='registeredStudent'. Error count: 1
> org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
> Field error in object 'registeredStudent' on field 'hobbies': rejected value [Singing,Sketching,Swimming]; codes [typeMismatch.registeredStudent.hobbies,typeMismatch.hobbies,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [registeredStudent.hobbies,hobbies]; arguments []; default message [hobbies]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'hobbies'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'Singing'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Singing"]

Pretty much, the Hobby with name = the String value of the checkboxes isn't being able to initialize anymore. I have tried removing the Hobby repository and it works perfectly. **Any further insight would be appreciated** as the only possible solution for now appears to be adding an extra *List<String> field* in my *Student* POJO class and using the values from checkboxes passed in the field to initialize the Hobby objects contained in *Student.hobbies*